# Disabling option to find printers by IP

Tags: windows-registry, printer, group-policy

On windows 10, we are looking for a way to remove/disable the "Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname" from the Add printer screen.

[image]

Any clue if there's a GPO or registry entry that could do this.  We haven't had any luck finding one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of such a specific option, only of stronger methods that disable adding
all printers.

**Method 1 : Hide Devices and Printers**

This is described in the Microsoft article
[Hide/Disable Devices in "Devices and Printers"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2018577/hide-disable-devices-in-devices-and-printers):

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
- Navigate to the policy
  *User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel*
- Double-click "Hide specified control panel items"
- Select Enable, click *Show*, and type `Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters`.

Optionally, once this policy is in place, use `regedit` to create the
following entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
```

and create a new Key `{2227a280-3aea-1069-a2de-08002b30309d}`
and give the "Default" key the value of `Printers`.

This will create a Printers folder on the desktop, which when opened gives only
the printer listing.

**Method 2 : Stop the user from adding or deleting printers**

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
- Navigate to the policy
  *User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers*
- Enable the following policies:

  - Prevent addition of printers
  - Prevent deletion of printers

Comment: Method 2 really is the only real solution to this situation.  There are too many ways around the first method.  Method 2 will allow you to lock down the printer configuration.

Comment: We agreed, we'll probably go the route of Method 2.  Thanks All